# I'm writing a REST Api using express.js (Mongoose )

Tags: rest, express, mongoose, postman-collection-runner

```
[
        {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 6,
            "sector": "Energy",
            "topic": "gas",
            "insight": "Annual Energy Outlook",
            "url": "http://www.eia.gov/outlooks/aeo/pdf/0383(2017).pdf",
            "region": "Northern America",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "January, 20 2017 03:51:25",
            "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "United States of America",
            "relevance": 2,
            "pestle": "Industries",
            "source": "EIA",
            "title": "U.S. natural gas consumption is expected to increase during much of the projection period.",
            "likelihood": 3
        },
        {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 6,
            "sector": "Energy",
            "topic": "oil",
            "insight": "Annual Energy Outlook",
            "url": "http://www.eia.gov/outlooks/aeo/pdf/0383(2017).pdf",
            "region": "Northern America",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "January, 20 2017 03:51:24",
            "published": "January, 09 2017 00:00:00",
            "country": "United States of America",
            "relevance": 2,
            "pestle": "Industries",
            "source": "EIA",
            "title": "Reference case U.S. crude oil production is projected to recover from recent declines.",
            "likelihood": 3
        }
]
```

here is my document so how can i store ??? enter image description here. i'm able to write REST Api only for one document but not for multiple document . I'm invoking service using POSTMAN.

Comment: u want to save multiple document at a time right?

Comment: yes and above my json data .. here  I have only two document but my actual data is too large , approx 20k lines .. so is it possible ? because I want to save my document via postman.

Answer (score 1):

You can create schema like this:

```
var Mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = Mongoose.Schema;

var SchemaName = new Schema({
    email: { type: String }
});

var CollectionName = Mongoose.model('CollectionName', SchemaName);
```

You can use this example to insert multiple records in one time.

```
var obj=[{
    email:"test@gmail.com"
},
{
    email:"test1@gmail.com"
},
{
    email:"test2@gmail.com"
}];

CollectionName.insertMany(obj)
.then(function(res) {
    console.log("=============insert===", res)
})
.
catch(function(err){
    console.log("============err nins===", err)
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion .. but I'm little bit confuse how to make schema ?? because i'm using mongoose so to insert any document first , we need to make a appropriate schema just like our json structure

Comment: thanks @harpreet but what if we want to take var obj=[{
    email:"test@gmail.com"
},
{
    email:"test1@gmail.com"
},
{
    email:"test2@gmail.com"
}];   , this json data with POSTMAN , then how we can set all the data on a object ?

Comment: can we do like this  var schemaName = new SchemaName ({ email:req.body.email });    CollectionName.insertMany(" obj ???not sure ")
.then(function(res) {
    console.log("=============insert===", res)
})

Answer (score 0):

so you want to inserty multiple documents at a time.

> in mongodb there is some limit of documet at a time you can save. it can support upto 16MB of BSON Document Size.
>   see it [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/)

now lets talk about [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/) documents at at a time.

*this following query inserts multiple dicuments at a time*:

```
db.CollectionName.insertMany(
   [ <document 1> , <document 2>, ... ],
   {
      ordered: <boolean[Default True]>
   }
);
```

now insted of   `[ <document 1> , <document 2>, ... ]` you can pass your document. in **Array** of **Objects** format (as you given).

Comment: thanks saikat .. but how i can bind my json data in mongoose Schema ? give me some suggestion about that because my problem is about schema and to invoke service.

Comment: as per my understanding, you have an express app, and a route, and already database connection is done, now you want to give a post request with your data and save it. am i right?
if you need only the schema, i will update in the same answer.

Comment: yes u r right .. let's take a scenario , DB Connection is already done .we have all the data in postman body and one POST request ,    for this json we need a Mongoose Schema that will looks like

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dataVisulations= mongoose.Schema({ _id:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, end_year:String,intensity:Number, sector:String,topic:String,insight:String,
url:String,  region:String,start_year:String,
            impact:String,
            added:String,
            published:String,
            country:String,
            relevance:Number,
            pestle:String,
            source:String,
            title:String,
            likelihood:Number      
});
module.exports=mongoose.model('DataVisulation',dataVisulations);

Comment: and now we have a post request                                                                                 router.post('/',(req , res , next)=>{var dataVisulation = new DataVisulation({ end_year:req.body.end_year,........and so on for all the key ..})

Comment: now  ??? I'm facing problem here .. if i have only one document then i can do like. . dataVisulation.save().then( res.status(201).json({message:'data inserted ')}

Comment: thats what i wrote, insted of doing all this things, just `collectionaname.insertMany(ArrOfUrDoc,{ ordered: <boolean[Default]> });`